# Degenerate random variable

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, independence, joint-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent $rv$ such that $XY$ is a degenerate $rv$. Can I say that individually $X$ and $Y$ are also degenerate? Why?

Comment: Could you give us your definition of what is a degenerate random variable?

Comment: a degenerate distribution of random variable is the probability distribution of a random variable which only takes a single value (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution)

Comment: No. Only one of them needs to be. Let $X$ be zero with probability $1$ and let $Y$ be any finite-valued random variable.

Comment: To complete @Macro's thought, consider the contrapositive: when *both* $X$ and $Y$ are nondegenerate, independence implies $XY$ must be nondegenerate.  Therefore Macro has supplied all the possible counterexamples (up to permutation of $X$ and $Y$).

Comment: Let $(\Omega, \cal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X$ a random variable on $\Omega$. Let, also, $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a Borel function. Then:  
$X$ and $Y$ are independent $\Longleftrightarrow$ there exists some $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{P}[Y=t]=1$, that is $Y$ is a degenerate r.v.

Comment: The only thing that I could make out is that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then  
$\mathbb{P}[Y\in B]=0$ or $1$ for every Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$, since $\sigma(Y)\subseteq \sigma(X)$ and hence, $Y$ is independent of its self. Suppose, now, that $\mathbb{P}[Y\leq x]=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then:  
$\mathbb{P}[Y\in\mathbb{R}]=\mathbb{P}[\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}[Y\leq n]]\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[Y\leq n]=0$ which obviously is a contradiction since $\mathbb{P}[Y\in\mathbb{R}]=1$.

Answer (score 3):

**NO**. Let $X$ be any variable and $Y$ independent such that $Y=0$ with probability 1. Then $XY$ is degenerate, but $X$ need not be.

This was already answered in comments:

No. Only one of them needs to be. Let $X$ be zero with probability 1 and let $Y$ be any finite-valued random variable. – Macro

To complete @Macro's thought, consider the contrapositive: when both X and Y are nondegenerate, independence implies XY must be nondegenerate. Therefore Macro has supplied all the possible counterexamples (up to permutation of X and Y). – whuber